# How do I force a game to download saves Puzzle Quest from the Steam Cloud?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud, puzzle-quest

I have Puzzle Quest on Steam, and it [supports Steam Cloud](http://store.steampowered.com/news/4326/). I know that I had a save file in this game, but when I installed it and tried to play it, I did not have my saved game.

I tried to uncheck the "Enable Steam Cloud synchronization" checkbox in the settings window, and then closed the window, opened it, and rechecked the box. I also tried exiting and restarting Steam, verifying the game cache, and reinstalling the game. After doing all of these I still do not have the save file.

How can I force Steam to download my save file from the cloud?

Comment: [This thread from the Steam Forums](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2835542) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the Steam Cloud saves *do* download automatically. However, you have to click "Single Player" and then "Back" to get the option to continue, as discovered in [this thread](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1674049).